# On local development with Wordpress on iOS, resources fail to load

Tags: ios, wordpress, localhost

Have been developing a Wordpress theme using MAMP (localhost:81), and I am now testing some responsive parts on iOS (using my IP (192.168.1.15:81).

Some images are hard-coded (i.e. not changeable from the admin), using the following code:

```
<img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/brand-id.svg" onerror="this.src=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/brand-id.png" alt="Brand Name" />
```

It displays correctly both on localhost and IP, from desktop, but using the IP on iOS (8.1), it cannot find the resource, because it loads it in this form:

```
http://localhost:81/alexe.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/brand/images/brand-id.svg
```

I am using the Relative URL Wordpress plugin, but that seems to only work for loading the css/js/fonts.

Other details: the dynamic images (the ones uploaded from the cms) load perfectly.

How can I get the 'hard-coded' resources to switch between localhost and the IP, if necessary?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "It displays correctly both on localhost and IP, from desktop", you said. Is that on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, that is on the same machine (OSX), both the IP and localhost work and load the images correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't related to IOS, it will fail to read the correct path from any machine in the LAN, apart from your dev one.

**One of the solution is:**

To make WP to always run under `http://IP:port` rather than `http://localhost:port`

In your case, it looks like your WP is in a sub directory `/wp`, then login to admin panel, and go and update as below:

Settings > General > WordPress Address >> `http://192.168.1.15:81`

Settings > General > Site Address >> `http://192.168.1.15:81/wp`

It's also recommended to set the dev machine with a static/preserved IP address on the router, so it will always receive the same one.

I also like the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28837614/483779) posted by @asherstoppard Well, you can play around and find which fits you the best.

**One more tip:** Backup your database first, in case anything bad happened.

Comment: This worked, but I did have a little scare. You left out the subfolder `/alexe.ro/wp` so I had to replace it in phpMyAdmin. Thank you so much for the tip of backing up my db, as well.

You rock.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `wp-config.php` file.

```
define('WP_HOME','192.168.1.15:81');
define('WP_SITEURL','192.168.1.15:81');
```

Your `site_url()` will be set to `localhost:81` and as such will be attempting to access `localhost` on your device through `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Tried this and it 404s the content loop. Nothing except the menu. The same goes for the wp-admin, it loads a plain html version:

[Screenshot: Home on IP](http://mateitudor.com/clients/alexe.ro/home-ip.png)
[Screenshot: Home on local](http://mateitudor.com/clients/alexe.ro/home-local.png)
[Screenshot: Admin on local](http://mateitudor.com/clients/alexe.ro/admin-local.png)